# Why do (PHP) developers store sessions in project temp folder?

Tags: php, session

I've seen this many times, especially when inspecting (older) browsergame scripts, storing they user sessions in e.g. /project/sessions or /project/tmp. Is there any valid reason not to use the default session save path?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is so they can manage the directory permissions. Some projects are setup to do that by default in a develop mode, but aren't meant to stay like that in production.

Comment: Session data should not ideally be stored in the temp/ folder as that is the ***default*** so it's more secure to store data elseswhere. `$_SESSION` are by their very nature **temporary** values, they are not intended for long term storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path):

> **Warning**
>
> If you leave this set to a world-readable directory, *such as `/tmp` (the
>   default)*, other users on the server may be able to hijack sessions by
>   getting the list of files in that directory.

Also usually the default temporary directory get cleaned on reboot and session data may be lost.

Comment: Additional info: i'm running either on localhost for development or on a dedicated machine for production. So no worries. :) I get your point though, thanks.